# Grafana maps with rockset and dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, real-time, grafana, rockset

Hy all, i am using grafana with rockset to collect real time series form our dynamodb database, but we have the next problem in the plugin maps.

My data with the next query:

```
select country,real,_event_time from commons.Players
```

is

```
'US' '0.5' '2020-05-27T08:40:51.548000Z',
'UK' '0.2' '2020-05-27T08:40:50.548000Z'
```

I read that i must pase the country code in the group by:

```
select 
 country,sum(real) as total ,_event_time 
from commons.Players 
group by _event_time,country
```

but this doesn't work, I select the correct type of location data (countries) but impossible to see anything.

I don't have problem with any kind of graph but in the map is impossible to my to see the information. I have read documentation and really I don't understand the query that i must use in this part to see the data.

Thanks for everything.

Comment: Doing test all the point are always drawing in philipines??? Any idea?

Comment: Which "map" are you using = which panel type?

Comment: World map panel. But always display all the info in philipones... dont have sense.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your panel configuration so it is blind guess. Use query:

```
SELECT
  _event_time AS "time",
  country AS "code",
  real
FROM commons.Players
```

and configure `Map Data Options`->`Location Data: countries` to "translate" 2 letter country code to map coordinates.

Comment: Hi thanks but it dosent work, the type of the the country is null in the query explorer then i suposed that "code" dont work, even with _event_time is nor recognize as time in the query explorer.

Comment: @Deckard27 It was just guess, Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example